# Cloudflare "can't provide a secure connection" to subdomain with www prefix

Tags: subdomain, cloudflare, no-www, resolution, www

I have connected my site to the Cloudflare through A DNS record and CNAME too. For example:

- `A domain.com 109.106.***.** Proxied Auto`
- `CNAME www domain.com Proxied Auto`

The site works very fine at all, but the problem is with the subdomain. Created the subdomain and added to the Cloudflare with A record as below:

- `A subdomain 109.106.***.** Proxied Auto`

The subdomain works well when enter to the browser `https://subdomain.example.com` but if we write `https://www.subdomain.example.com` it says ->

> This site can’t provide a secure `connection www.networkmanager.example.com` uses an unsupported protocol.
> `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`

Also when i try to enter CNAME record for subdomain `www` as did for domain it says CNAME record already exist with that host.

This is the configuration at cloudflare:
[image]

This is the error I get when trying to open the page with `www` in front:
[image]

But the error doesn't happen when trying to open without `www.`

I am lost, any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: @EAKTEAM If you're using CloudFlare's [Universal SSL](https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/edge-certificates/universal-ssl/), which it appears you are, then that only covers first-level subdomains (`blog.example.com`), so you will receive an SSL error. See [this](https://developers.cloudflare.com/dns/manage-dns-records/how-to/create-subdomain/) CloudFlare doc regarding adding SSLs for deeper subdomains.

Comment: @EAKTEAM Adding `www` to a subdomain isn't all that common, so unless there's a specific reason you need to do that, I'd stick with just the first-level subdomain. Also, it's a little hard to tell exactly what you have in your DNS, but  it appears you added `A` records for every subdomain plus a `CNAME` for each too, which is not really necessary. Since it appears you already have an `A` recording pointing your root domain to your IP address, then for subdomains you only need a `CNAME` to point to your root domain - see [this](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/how-do-i-add-a-cname-record/59).

Comment: @dan I understand that, but many sites have back linked my subdomain with www in front of it and not without www. So this is why i need to redirect or something like that www to non www subdomain

Comment: @EAKTEAM Then you'll need to either purchase the Advanced Certificate Manager, to cover more than one level of subdomain, or purchase a separate SSL certificate and upgrade to the Business or Enterprise plans as covered [here](https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/edge-certificates/universal-ssl/limitations/#full-setup). If the backlinks have `https` in them, then redirecting to a `non-www` subdomain won't work properly until you have an SSL for the `www` subdomain as well. If the backlinks only have `http` though, then you can redirect to `https://subdomain.example.com` using Page Rules.